# Datazen, Invalid query - Datazen.Server.Service.Jobs.StatisticsCollectionJob

Tags: sql-server, datazen-server

I receiving every few minutes error in Datazen Server.

> Error description: **"Datazen.Server.Service.Jobs.StatisticsCollectionJob"** in Datazen Control Panel Log Viewer window.

Could you please advice what I need to check to fix this problem?

Comment: Somebody had a similar problem?

Comment: I've seen this error a lot, but I have yet to find out what is causing it. I've tried looking further into the log files, but so far I have not found any reason for this error unfortunately.